# How to write double precision floats to postgres over jdbc from spark

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc

I'm trying to write data to Postgres from Spark; I have a DataFrame consisting of some strings, some floating point values, and some integers of differing widths, and I've found that if I don't pass a schema, I get an error that looks like this:

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Unsupported type in postgresql: ByteType 
at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.PostgresDialect$.getJDBCType(PostgresDialect.scala:83)
```

If I *do* pass a schema, I find that I can't get spark to recognize any double precision data type

```
val postgresSchema = "c1 VARCHAR(10000), c2 BIGINT, c3 BIGINT, c4 FLOAT8, c5 FLOAT8, c6 TINYINT, c7 VARCHAR(10000), c8 VARCHAR(10000)"

dataFrame
.coalesce(POSTGRES_WRITE_PARTITIONS)
.write
.option("createTableColumnTypes", postgresSchema)
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.jdbc(jdbcURL, table, connectionProperties)
```

I've tried everything I can think of based on the [Postgresql Numeric Data Type Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html) of what might work, and none of the data types appear to work.

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
DataType float8 is not supported.(line 1, pos 86)

User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
DataType double is not supported.(line 1, pos 86)

User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
DataType real is not supported.(line 1, pos 86)

User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
DataType float(53) is not supported.(line 1, pos 86)
```

I also tried using `DOUBLE PRECISION` as the data type, which gives:

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input 'PRECISION' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 93)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put double precision column in createTableColumnTypes, SparkSQL will automatically create double column if you mentioned in schema , sample code below

```
    for (String fieldName : schema.keySet()) {
        String fieldType = schema.get(fieldName).toLowerCase();
        fieldName = fieldName.toLowerCase();
        DataType sparkDataType = DataTypeConverterUtil.getSparkDataTypeFromJavaType(fieldType);
        StructField structField = new StructField(fieldName, sparkDataType, true, Metadata.empty());
        structFields[count++] = structField;
    }
    StructType sparkDataSchema = new StructType(structFields);
    Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").schema(sparkDataSchema)
            .option("delimiter", dataDelimeter).option("header", true).option("quote", "\"")
            .option("escape", "\"").load(paths.split(","));

    df.write().option("truncate", true).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("createTableColumnTypes", customSchema)
            .jdbc(url, tableName, connectionProperties);
```

You have to add double column mentioned in sparkDataSchema